# How do I resolve the "no-name-in-module" error in Pylint when using Parler's TranslatedFields?

Tags: python, django, pylint

I have the following class in models.py:

```
class Family(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    translations = TranslatedFields(name=models.CharField(max_length=255))
```

When I try to import the "FamilyTranslation" model for various purposes

`from .models import FamilyTranslation`

Pylint detects the "E0611:no-name-in-module" error.

The table with the translations is created, the code works, but Pylint doesn't recognize the model.

I have tried some pylint plugins to make Parler's automatic models recognized, but it doesn't work.

I have already checked the `__init__.py` file, and it is correct.

If possible, I would prefer not to explicitly declare all the "Translation" models from Parler.